# ASP.NET MVC 5. The resource cannot be found error on navigating to AreaName/Home/Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, visual-studio-2013

I converted a ASP.NET 4 WebForm website project from VS2010 to a ASP.NET 4.5 Web application project in VS2013. Then I created an Area in this new project and copied the Controllers, Models and views files from another VS2012 MVC4 project to this new Web App project. The application works fine when I navigate to the WebForms pages. But when I navigate to the MVC views, I get the following error `The resource cannot be found localhost:1234/AreaName/Home/Index`. I have the Home controller and Index action method and Index.cshtml. It works in the VS2012 project but there is no Area there. My 'AreaNameAreaRegisteration.cs file has:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "AreaName_default",
                "AreaName/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

**EDIT**

I just did the following: Added a new controller called 'JustTestController', right clicked on its Index  action method, clicked on 'Add View', it created a view Index.cshtml. Now when I browse to `http://localhost:1234/AreaName/JustTest/Index`, the view is displayed. So the question is why when I copy/paste the conrollers/models/views from another project (created in VS2012) those views give the above error even though manually creating a controller and corresponding views of its actions do display without error. Is there something I need to do for those controllers/views that I copied/pasted from the VS2012 project?

**Issue Resolved**

I have resolved the issue (thanks to Erik). Please see my comments below.

Comment: Are you calling `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in your global.asax?  Did you also add the relevant MVC web.config entries?

Comment: @Erik, yes I did add the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in the Global.asax.cs. I did add the relevant MVC web.config but maybe you can point out which of those MVC entries I should check if they are there.

Comment: You really aren't giving us any information to go on.  Obviously, MVC is working.  So there must be an issue with the controller.  Compare it to the controller you just created.

Comment: Many thanks to @Erik for his input. There was namespace issue at many places. The objects controllers/models/views from the VS2012 project had the name of the namespace as the name of VS2012 project. In the new project I changed that to the name of the new project and everything is working. So, if a class was surrounded by using namespace OldProjectName{...}, I surrounded it by NewProjectName{...}.

Comment: In the future it might be a good idea to use Route Debugger (you can nuget it). See Phil Hackk's blog post on Route Debugger saves a lot of headaches.